History of Leibniz' notation
Does anybody have an idea what manuscript this page (with Leibniz's differential notation) comes from?

This is from the archive in Hannover, Germany. Search https://writings.stephenwolfram.com/2013/05/dropping-in-on-gottfried-leibniz/ Stephan Wolfram shared the photos.
